# Values of Argv when something is not entered from command line

Tags: c++

Hi I was wondering what values would argv[1] or argv[2] be, if i failed to provide it with command line arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be <strike>garbage</strike> `NULL`.

Therefore you should always first test the `argc` (argument count) before trying to access the command line arguments.

See [this](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong as `argv[1]` wouldn't contain garbage, it would contain `NULL`.

Comment: It would be more correct to say "`argv[argc]` will be `NULL`". `argv[1]` would be `NULL` if `argc` is 1 (which is nearly always the case if no parameters are passed to the program in a 'hosted environment', but not guaranteed).  Of course, `argv[2]` (which the OP asked about) would be undefined in that case.

Answer (score 7):

You've gotten an amazing number of incorrect answers to this. With nothing entered on the command line, `argv[0]` will still normally contain the name of the program, so `argc` will be 1. `argv[argc]` will contain a null pointer (always, on every conforming implementation of C or C++). In the C standard that requirement is at the second bullet of §5.1.2.1.1/2. In the C++ standard it's at §3.6.1/2.

Comment: This is a nice detail. but the other answers aren't 'incorrect'.  if you de-reference argv[1] you will get garbage or a segfault, the fact that the value is supposed to be null is sort of beside the point.  It's just as correct to say that arg[1] 'contains' garbage than it is to say that argv[0] 'contains' the program name.

Answer (score -1):

a segfault if you are lucky, garbage if you aren't.

The only safe way to use argv, is to treat it as an array of argc elements.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < argc; ++ii)
{
    // safe to use argv[ii];
    cout << argv[ii];
}

int ix = somevalue;
if (ix >= 0 && ix < argc)
{
    // safe to use argv[ix];
}
```

Note to Jerry.  A segfault is what you get when you de-reference NULL on most architectures.